# Extract first characters of a string in Excel with a space

Tags: excel

I'm trying to extract only the characters (letters) to the left into a separate column.  I have tried `=MID(A1,1,SEARCH(" ",A1,1))`and this works on everything except on the ARNC1 and GALE1 strings.

```
ARNC1 01202017 C 13
AAPL 12232016 C 113
CMI 12232016 C 135
JCP 12302016 C 10.5
PSX 12232016 C 88
GALE1 01192018 C 3
```

For example I need to see.

```
ARNC
AAPL
CMI
JCP
PSX
GALE
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,1,SEARCH(" ",A1,1)),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,""),0,"")
```

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Even if there is already an answer, just for free:

```
=MID(A1,1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9," "},A1&"0123456789 "))-1)
```